# Hide all children DOM elements until found a <hr/>

Tags: jquery

I wonder how to hide all elements until found the first `<hr/>`. Then the loop should stop

```
    <div class='row-father'>
   <legend> Title here </legend>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <hr/>
    </div>
```

...

```
$('.row-father').find('*').each(function(){
    if ($(this) != '<hr/>')
        $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: Something like `if (!$(this).is('hr')) {`

Comment: `$(this).prop("tagName") === "HR"` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use this: `$('.row-father > hr:first').prevAll(':not(legend)').hide();`  See http://api.jquery.com/prevall/

Comment: I reedited the request. i think now should be $('hr').first().prevAll().hide(), shouldn't it?

Comment: It seems to work with a only difference I need to set up an upper limit  as well, as there is a <legend> tag up in the dom stack  that should hide.

Comment: @Kandinski - i'm not sure what you mean by that, but you could count them and use `lt` or `gt` if you need to only hide a fraction of the preceding elements.  Or you can include/exclude elements from `prevAll` using a selector.

Comment: I reedited, I added a legend tag, that is being hidden too and it shouldn't

Comment: @Kandinski - you might want to think a little bit more next time before writing the question. You've morphed it twice since asked, changing it fundamentally.  See my update.

Answer (score 1):

You can detect this by using `.is('hr')`.

Code:

```
$('.row-father').find('*').each(function() {
     if (!$(this).is('hr')) {
         $(this).hide();
     }
     else {
         return false;
     }
});
```

Example can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jp2KK/).

Answer (score 1):

`$('.row-father').find('hr').eq(0).prevAll('.row-fluid').hide();`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/eJPQt/)

Answer (score 0):

you can also use

`$('.row-fluid:first').nextUntil("hr").andSelf().hide();`

http://jsfiddle.net/gDGmX/3/

**Edit:**

if You want to replace `<hr/>` with a div contains text , for example :

```
   <div class='row-father'>
   <legend> Title here </legend>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <div>test</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <div class="row-fluid">...</div>
        <hr/>
    </div>
```

you could try this code :

```
$('.row-fluid:first').nextUntil("div>:contains('test')").andSelf().hide();
```

Comment: +1 for `andSelf()`. Never heard of it. But not upvoting because this code does not work.

Comment: Yes, I've checked that. It should only color the top 2 `divs` i.e. no 1 and no 2  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jashwant/gDGmX/2/)

Comment: I like your answer but is it possible to replace nextUntil("hr") with something like nextUntil("div:contains('Date')")..I cannot make it work